# demo Docusign API shows only envelopes from last month

Tags: docusignapi

a month ago Docusign demo interface and API started to show only envelopes from the last month (moving window, so today it shows envelopes from 2016/11/21). Can I change that behavior to keep and show all envelopes as it did before?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot. Envelopes are only kept in Demo for 30 days.